# How to get the Incremental data from config file to get last 5 days data only

Tags: python, sql, json, config

Currently i am using a config file in python to get incremental data from an api. Below is a snippet of the config file

```
[
 {
   "id" : 123,
   "input":{
    "name" :    ,
    "path" :     ,
    "format":     , 
    "paramters":{
                 "table_name" : "test"
      },
     "query" : "select * from test where type_id='1234' and time>= '2023-04-20T00:46:26+00:00'"
  },
]
```

Now i am manually changing the TIME path of the sql query but i want a solution where i dont need to manually change the date.

I did try a bunch of different ways but at the end i am not getting any value at my output file unless i give a date

1. time >= 'DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL 7 DAY'
2. time = DateDiff(left(time,19), today(), day) <5 - this should ideally give incremental value in sql but here i am not able to pass this statement in python

Comment: (1) What is the datatype of column `time`? (2) What happens when  you try to two solutions you listed? Please provide the complete error message, if any. (3) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, postgresql, oracle...?

Comment: @GMB time has varchar datatype. To your second question, the api passes but the output file does not show any records at all. If i manually input date it shows data from the input date to the current time. This is a config file which will be used in python and later run in MSSQL

Comment: So Python reads the config, then calls some function to run the database query? Or does python just set the query in the config?
Either way, why cant you just create the date string in python, then append it to whatever the query is? Simply get the current date/time in the same format as youre manually adding to the query and append it

Comment: Oops didn't realise that you want to set the query to >= 5 days ago. Still should be able to do it as I described.

Comment: @mrblue6 the config file is in .txt format which i use in a POST request in api to extract a file. How do i append a datetime query to the 'TIME' part to get last 3/5 days data? Do i ave to convert it into a .json file? Sorry if this seems silly

Comment: I was wondering why you, yourself compute the date part in query. In most of major databases, such as Oracle(trunct(sysdate(-such as trunc(sysdate-7)), or Mysql(date(sysdate()-7)),SQL server(getdate() - 7) provide solution for such problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make it a json, but it will possibly be easier for you to parse a json config because it can be turned into a dictionary, making it very easy to parse. But txt file will also work if thats what you want.

```py
#import datetime module
import datetime
#Get datetime for right now
tod = datetime.datetime.now()
#create time delta of how many days to go back
d = datetime.timedelta(days = 5)
#simple subtraction
a = tod - d
#format the date to the format you want. The 00:00 at the end is to just set milliseconds to 0 because datetime can't parse ms like that (I think?)
formatted_string = a.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00")
print(formatted_string)
#prints 2023-04-19T18:39:38+00:00 (ie. 5 days before when I ran this)

#I will assume here you open and read your config file
#assuming query looks like this in the config: "query" : "select * from test where type_id='1234' and time>= "
#query variable is your query from the config file
#Initialising query below because I don't have your config file
query = "select * from test where type_id='1234' and time>= "
query += formatted_string
print(query)
#prints select * from test where type_id='1234' and time>= 2023-04-19T18:42:23+00:00

#now you can write this back to your config and do whatever else is needed
```

Comment: Yep, thats what i did, had to change the whole time variable with your script and write the query line using writeLines. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mrblue6 and others help, i just need to rewrite the line containing the time and place the quotations correctly :-

```
query = "\"query\""":""\"select* from test where type_id='1234' and time>=" "'"+formatted_string+"'"  (the file was not running without the quotes correct)

with open('abcd.txt) as f:
lines = f.readLines()

lines[10] = f'{query}"\n'
with open('abcd.txt','w') as file:
 file.writeLines(lines)
```